# Recovering corrupted data from usb sticks

Tags: data-recovery, usb-drive

I have been asked by a friend to try to recover some photos from two usb sticks and have come to the conclusion I know nothing about these sorts of things.

A little bit of background about both usb drives:

- they are both FAT32
- first drive (4GB) - after doing a brief fsck on it, I removed the dirty bit and got the message that there is some discrepancy between original and backup (don't really know what that means). After exiting the process prematurely, I could see what was on the drive, but not open or copy any of the files. I even left gparted do a "check and fix" overnight (which also does a fsck on it) and it did not go over the step I described above. I even tried another tool, photorec, but that also froze. What would be the best way to recover data from this drive, if any?
- second drive (16GB) - I can't even attempt to fix it because it seems the partitions are bad or something. It has empty space at the begining and a partition at the end, yet if you sum them up, it exceeds the max space of the usb drive itself (gparted seems to complain about this also). What is going on here and what could I do?

I guess the bottom line uestion would be: how did these drives get into this state? They haven't been used all that much, so I am really confused. Could unsafe removal have caused this?

Should I even attempt recovering on a linux machine? Tools like Recuva don't even show the drives properly on my linux box. Also, is there a way (and I might not know how this works entirely) to basically copy the drives bit by bit somewhere and through that have the files restored?

Comment: If the usb drive is physically intact I can recommend recuva, I have been able to recover many photos with that tool.

Comment: You could take a look at `dd` (or the improved variant `dcfldd` if it is available for your OS flavor) to perform the bitwise copy of the USB stick to an image file you mentioned. Some information on that can be found [here on askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318893/how-do-i-create-a-bit-identical-image-of-a-usb-stick).